# Using Flash AS3 Facebook API for Desktop (Not Flex)

Tags: facebook, actionscript-3, flash, air, desktop

I'm currently building an AIR program for Desktop using AS3 in Flash (not FLEX). I want to be able to share the text within a certain text field to the user's wall. For the life of me, I cannot find a tutorial on how to do this without FLEX.

I've downloaded the Facebook Actionscript API (Graph API 1.8.1 Desktop SWC), and imported it into my project, but I can't login or post.
https://code.google.com/archive/p/facebook-actionscript-api/downloads

How would I go about this?

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't"? What happens exactly? What error do you get? What does your code look like?

Comment: Looks like there are plenty of examples in the same repository that can get you started, including the "FB_AS3_API_HelloWorldExamples.zip" ?

Answer (score -1):

There is an AS3 Facebook API by Adobe:

https://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/

You need to handle the login first, but here is how you post to wall:

```
var params:Object =
{   
  message: text,
  link: 'your link here',
  caption: 'Text to display 1',
  name: 'Text to display 2',
  description: 'Description',
  picture: 'image url here'
};

Facebook.api( 'me/feed', onComplete, params, "POST" );

function onComplete( response:Object, fail:Object ):void 
{
    trace( JSON.encode(response)  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I was having difficulty logging into Facebook via the API to actually post directly on the wall instead of posting a link to the wall. With the issues I faced, I found it easier to post the data to a mySQL database via Adobe Air and using the URL post method to link to the page with the appropriate database information.